# Update one value in parent activity from a child activity while retaining all remaining original values on the parent

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an input form where I collect 4 values in a text field that are tied to the FirstActivity. The user enters 4 values and clicks a button which will present the user with 2 options that are tied to SecondActivity.

Upon clicking one of the options in SecondActivity, he is presented with a 3rd screen with a search option. Upon searching, he is presented with search results as a list.

When the user clicks on one of the results, I want to update one field in FirstActivity while retaining all the values that the user selected initially. I used the Intent flags to retain the state and it works except for one problem - I dont see the updated value in the first screen.

PROBLEM: While this code helps me retain the initial state in FirstActivity, it doesn't update the CopiesValue when I return to FirstActivity. I want the copies value to be updated with the value that was selected in ThirdActivity. All original values on FirstActivity are retained though...

**I want the updated value from ThirdActivity to reflect on the first screen once a value is selected on the third screen.**

Here is my code within the onClickListener in ThirdActivity:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Object o = lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
        String str = (String) o; 
        Globals g = Globals.getInstance();
        ((FirstActivity)g.getFirstContext()).getSettingHolder().setSelectedCopiesValue(5);
        Intent intent = new Intent(g.getFirstContext(), FirstActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        finish();
    }
});
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml entry:

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.FirstActivity"
        android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|fontScale"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activity.SecondActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".activity.FirstActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activity.ThirdActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".activity.FirstActivity" />
    </activity>
```

Comment: post your `globals` and `first activity` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LocalBroadcastRecevier` will do the trick over here...

**Register receiver in you FirstActivity:**

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Handle data coming from thirdActivity

  }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // Register to receive messages.
  // We are registering an observer (mMessageReceiver) to receive Intents
  // with actions named "custom-event-name".
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
      new IntentFilter("custom-event-name"));
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
  super.onDestroy();
}
```

**Add these lines to you ThirdActivity(which is a sender)**

```
private void sendMessage() {
  Intent intent = new Intent("custom-event-name");
  intent.putExtra("KEY", "Value");
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}

// OnClick event of something...
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  sendMessage();
}
```

Comment: tried your option. Using this I can pass the value but the view on the screen doesnt go back to the view related to FirstActivity though. I may be doing something wrong here.... Any ideas on how to show the view for the first activity ?

Comment: View in the sense.. `FirstActivity` doesn't showing up?

Comment: Yes, the first screen doesnt appear. In my original code, the intent was taking me back to the first screen with original values.

Comment: You have to finish it manually. Try this way-- `A-> startActivity(B)->startActivityForResult(C)-->From C, send broadcast, setResult(Itent data), finish()-->B's onActivityResult()--finish B`. In short, C will tell B to finish iteself via onActivityResult process.

Comment: I was able to get it to work with a small change. I will post my solution below in a separate comment with some additional details. Your answer helped me get there half the way ! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want using `EventBus`, create a model class to pass data from third to first activity

Add below dependency in gradle

```
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
```

**CopyModel.java**

```
public class CopyModel{
  private int copies;
  public CopyModel(int copies){
    this.copies = copies;
  }

  public int getSelectedCopies(){
     return copies;
  }
}
```

**ThirdActivity**

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Object o = lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
        String str = (String) o; 
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new CopyModel(5)); //<-- pass data before navigating to first activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(g.getFirstContext(), FirstActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        finish();
    }
});
```

**FirstActivity**

```
private int selectedCopies; //global declaration

@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onEvent(CopyModel copyModel) {
       //get your selected copies and assign it to global variable
       this.selectedCopies = copyModel.getSelectedCopies();
    }

 @Override
 public void onResume(){
    //you can use new selectedCopies value here and write code to update UI based on new value
 }
```

Comment: @ranjan ks, tried your option as well. First screen comes up but doesnt get the updated value. All original values still remain on the screen.

Comment: You will get the values on onEvent method, use that to assign to any global values

Comment: How do I update the view with the updated data ? the UI screen doesnt get this updated data. I am able to get back the data in the onEvent method but the screen doesnt get refreshed with the updated value. Is there any other method that I need to call like onResume or onReenter ? Tried onResume but it had no effect

Comment: Check out my edit, you need to write code to update Ui in `onResume`, which will have new `selectedCopies` value by time you navigate back to `firstactivity`

Comment: the onResume function doesnt refresh the screen with the values either.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above from **@Wizard**, I had to do a few more changes to get my app working.I can now see the updated value from third activity on the first activity screen, while all other initial values are retained.

In the Broadcast.onReceive method, I had to call the intent on the same activity (FirstActivity).

***I am not sure if this is a good practice to call an intent on itself while in the same activity. Will this cause any performance issues ?Can anyone please comment on the best practices here ??***

**In FirstActivity**

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String selectedCopies = intent.getStringExtra("selectedCopies");
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FirstActivity.class);
        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(intent1);
    }
};
```

**In ThirdActivity (on click of list item)**

```
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Object o = lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String selectedCopies = (String) o; //As you are using Default String Adapter

            Intent intent = new Intent("custom-event-name");
            intent.putExtra("selectedCopies", selectedCopies);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(g.getMainContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    });
```